# add products button not visible in quote line editor in salesforce cpq

Tags: cpq

The add products button is not visible in quote line editor in salesforce cpq. I have logged in as sys admin, but still not visible. No buttons at all - any pointers?

Comment: Go to page layout and in the button list in the left side check if this button was dragged on page layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Custom Actions** home page and check if **Add Product** is active or not. if not, then make it Active and also check the layout for the Custom Action

[image]

Comment: yes, that's what I did. It was not there so I manually added it.

Comment: Need to execute the cpq scripts again